# Is there a way to find out if load on Elastic stack is growing?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have just started learning Elastic stack and I already have to diagnose production issue. Our setup from time to time has problems with pulling messages from ActiveMq to Elastic Search using Logstash. There is a lag which can be 1-3 hours.

One suspicion is that maybe load went up after latest release of our application.
Is there a way to find out total size of messages stored grouped by month? Not only their number but total size of them. Maybe documents' size went up not number of documents.

Answer (score 0):

Start with setting up a production monitoring instance to provide detailed statistics on your cluster: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.1/monitoring-production.html

This will allow you to get at those metrics like messages/month, average document size, index performance, buffer load, etc. A bit more detail on internal performance is available with https://visualvm.github.io/

While putting that piece together, you can also tweak Logstash performance e.g.

> Tune Logstash worker settings:
>
> Begin by scaling up the number of pipeline workers by using the -w flag. This will increase the number of threads available for filters and outputs. It is safe to scale this up to a multiple of CPU cores, if need be, as the threads can become idle on I/O.
>
> You may also tune the output batch size. For many outputs, such as the Elasticsearch output, this setting will correspond to the size of I/O operations. In the case of the Elasticsearch output, this setting corresponds to the batch size.

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/performance-troubleshooting.html